# Python : clear a log file

Tags: python, logging

I develop a client-server application and I have log in the server, so I use the `logging` module. I would like to create a command in the server to clear the file.

I have test with `os.remove()` but after, the log doesn't work.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this log being written to by a daemon process? You'd have to signal to the daemon that the log file's been removed so it can close/reopen the log file handle and start using the new log file. Otherwise it'll just keep writing to the old one, which will still exist somewhere until all filehandles on it are closed.

Comment: Give `mode="w"` to [`logging.FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It might be better to truncate the file instead of removing it. The easiest solution is to reopen the file for writing from your clearing function and close it:

```
with open('yourlog.log', 'w'):
    pass
```

Answer (score 16):

Just try to add a `'w'` as argument:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('debug.log', mode='w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Building up on Steffen B's answer: when using the `logging.basicConfig` function, one can also use this to rewrite the file instead of appending to it:

```
logging.basicConfig(
        # specify the filename
        filename=<PATH TO THE FILE>,
        # If filename is specified, open the file in this mode. Defaults to 'a'.
        filemode="w",
    )
```

More information can be found [in the dedicated section of the 'logging' module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).