# How to clear the log file and write it again?

Tags: python

I create the log file by this way:

```
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger("plus_dig_cname")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fh = logging.FileHandler( fdoc_log + "/plus_dig_cname.log" )

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(fh)
```

and when the size of plus_dig_cname.log is bigger than 300MB,I handle it by a shell script, the main process is:

```
 mv $LOG_DIR/$1 $LOG_DIR/$1.bk
 [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1
 touch $LOG_DIR/$1
 [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1
 chmod 666 $LOG_DIR/$1
 [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1
```

just mv it and touch a new one. 
**The problem is the logger can't wirte anything in the 
file of plus_dig_cname.log. The logging can't work.**
 Maybe it can be solved it by:

```
with open( "plus_dig_cname.log", "w" ):
               pass
```

this way can get a new log file by Python. But i want to get the new log file by Bash.


**So, why the logging can't work after "mv touch chmod"?**

Thank you

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898997/python-clear-a-log-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/logging.html#rotatingfilehandler) to have this handled for you.

For example:

```
MAX_SIZE = 300 * 1024 * 1024
LOG_PATH = fdoc_log + "/plus_dig_cname.log"
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH, maxBytes=MAX_SIZE, backupCount=5)
```

This will create 5 backups of 300MB each.

Answer (score 1):

The file is opened when you create [`FileHandler()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ef44e1b740cb/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l965) or on the first write to it. If you move the file; it's gone.

You could use `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` as @sberry suggested to rotate the file using Python.

If you rotate log files externally e.g., using [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) then you could notify your script that the file is gone e.g., by restarting it or sending a signal in the postrotate step.

Your script could reopen the file automatically if you use something like inotify to detect the change. Compare how `tail -f` and `tail -F` work.